# Django ORM select_related with multiple foreign keys?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Sld(models.Model):
    sld_name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True)
    tld = models.ForeignKey('db.Tld', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Tld(models.Model):
    tld_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Path(models.Model):
    path_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sld = models.ForeignKey('db.Sld', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I would like to execute the following query using Django's ORM:

```
SELECT 
t1.path_name,
t2.sld_name,
t3.tld_name
FROM path t1
LEFT JOIN sld t2
ON (t2.id = t1.sld_id)
LEFT JOIN tld t3
ON (t2.tld_id = t3.id);
```

Here are a few attempts:

```
urls = Path.objects.select_related().values('sld_name', 'tld_name', 'path_name')

urls = Path.objects.all().select_related().values()

urls = Path.objects.select_related('sld').select_related('tld').values()
```

What am I missing here?

The data should look like this:

```
{
'sld_name':'google', 
'tld_name':'com',
'path_name':'/'
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
urls = Path.objects.values('sld__sld_name', 'sld__tld__tld_name', 'path_name')
```

No need to hit additionally `select_related` with `values` as it fetch only one request with all values you need.